# Find the next Number?

Tags: lateral-thinking, number-sequence

Find out the next number in the following **Series**

5 , 7 , 12 , 13 , 9 , **?** .

Hint:

> Square root.

Comment: note that this is tagged with lateral thinking, which means the answer might not be purely algebraic. I have been trying to find patterns in the english words and roman numerals but currently I have nothing.

Comment: is this a series or a sequence?

Comment: I voted to close because as **too broad** because there are already at least two answers that appear to be valid.  Please refine or extend the question.

Comment: @Jishnu Chandran: If you want to add a hint or otherwise clarify your question, ***log in*** to do it.  We just rejected a [suggested edit](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/22410) from an anonymous user.  You can freely edit your own posts, but, for your protection, this must be done under the original user account.  It looks like you may have tried to edit your question without logging into your account.

Comment: @Jishnu Chandran Please update the question with some helpful hints.

Comment: @KNeerajLal : I have updated one hint, this one can clearly solve the answer.

Comment: @JishnuChandran Yes, I get it now :) Please reopen the question mods. :)

Answer (score 10):

> 4.

Because:

Let's name the numbers

$x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, x_6$.
We need to find $x_6$.

> Adding the numbers 2 by 2 in such a a way that their indexes sum up to 7 we get:
>  $x_3 + x_4 = 12+13 = 25 = 5^2$
>  $x_2 + x_5 = 7+9 = 16 = 4^2$
>  $x_1 + x_6 = 5+4 = 9 = 3^2$
>  It's about perfect squares

Comment: Number order is a bit strange if this is th answer

Comment: I admit, is kind of a long shot, but it's all I have.

Comment: i love this answer. if it's not the right one, it should be.

Comment: I agree @Anthony,but the outcome is not correct.

Comment: @Marius and fine effort in your perspective.Should i provide a hint.

Comment: Hint : Square root.

Comment: @JishnuChandran: This answer is pointing out that $\sqrt{x_3+x_4}\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\sqrt{x_2+x_5}\in\mathbb{N}$, and is guessing that $\sqrt{x_1+x_6}\in\mathbb{N}$ and that $\sqrt{x_1+x_6}=2\times\sqrt{x_2+x_5}-\sqrt{x_3+x_4}$ (by extrapolation), and concluding that $x_6 = \left(2\times\sqrt{x_2+x_5}-\sqrt{x_3+x_4}\right)^2-x_1$, so I don’t see how your hint rules out this answer. If anything, it supports this answer.

Answer (score 2):

> 22

## Why?

> 5 + 7 = 12, 13 + 9 = 22

## Other

If We want go on with sequence of numbers, I think It goes like that:

> 5 + 7 = 12 , 13 + 9 = 22, 23 + 11=34, 35 + 15 = 50 
> If `5,7=12 and the 13,9` I think You did 7+2, 12 -> 2. So, 23+11 , 9 (13+9) and 2 (22 -> 2).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, and Puzzling Stack Exchange in particular.   (The first part of) your answer is no less plausible than any of the others that have been posted.  You’ll find that the questions here are usually trickier than that, but not always; there’s no harm in offering a plausible guess if the correct answer hasn’t been revealed yet.  But the second part of your answer (the “**Other**” edit) is very confusing.  You seem to be using `,` (comma) to mean `+` (plus) and `-` (hyphen) to delimit a list,  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  except where you say “…22, 23…” and “…34, 35…”, in which you seem to be using `,` (comma) to delimit a list.  And you do use `+` after that, so why are you using `,` (comma) to mean `+` (plus) in the first place? If you’re extrapolating from $n_4=n_3+1$ to assume $n_7=n_6+1$ and $n_{10}=n_9+1$, you should say so. And where are you getting your suggested values for $n_8$ and $n_{11}$? Your last line (starting with “If”) doesn’t make any sense to me at all.  You probably shouldn’t be using backticks around “5,7=12 and the 13,9” like that. What does “2” have to do with anything?

Comment: P.S. I see that you’re just learning English. For your information, in ordinary English sentences, we capitalize the first word, (most) names (e.g., “Stack Exchange”), many abbreviations (e.g., “Q&A” for “question and answer”), and the pronoun “I” — and not much else — so “We”, “It”, and “You” should not be capitalized.

Answer (score 1):

> I think 4 is the answer.
>  12 to 7 difference is 5 so 13 to 9 difference is 4.

Comment: No.This is not the answer.

Comment: Oh Okay. let me think :)

Comment: While I’ve seen some very weird questions (puzzles) and some very weird answers (some of which have been marked as correct) on this site, it’s conventional for sequences/series of numbers to work *sequentially*. Your answer would make a little bit of sense if $n_1-n_2=n_3$, but that’s not the case. If you’re going to suggest a non-sequential answer to a series question, you should at least acknowledge that it is a non-sequential answer and, ideally, provide a rationale as to why it is likely to be the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to try :)

Is it

> 8

Because

> 13 - 12 = 1; 9 - 7 = 2; x - 5 = should be 3

so x = 8.

Comment: Please someone find the answer I am really tired to checking if answered at any time whatsoever ...

Answer (score 1):

It's

> **14**

because

> if we translate each number to a letter corresponding to its position in the alphabet, we get **E G L M I** and so of course we're missing **N** (=14) because then we can spell the word **MINGLE**, mingled.

Comment: That word is somewhat appropriate to the inputs of this puzzle. But, aside from that, you could also use gimlet, midleg, and a few non-standard ones (e.g., gimble, leming, and milage).

Answer (score 0):

> Is the Answer 22?

Because

> 12- 7 = 5 & 22 - 13 = 9

Comment: Your answer is mathematically equivalent to [Ronronner’s answer](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/38348/19765), which was posted before yours.  That’s not a big deal in this case, the time delta was 18 seconds, and, IMO, anything under 42 seconds is a tie.  However, that post presents the result in a straightforward, constructive manner (here’s how you get from the given numbers to the missing number) while your uses a backwards approach (Poof!  Here’s the answer, which I pulled out of thin air; now, here’s an argument that suggests that it fits the question.)